# Does BizTalk 2010 Support HIPAA 278 - 005010X216

Tags: xsd, biztalk, hipaa

I looked at the [BizTalk HIPAA 5010 Version Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629729.aspx) page and they have the 278 schema listed, but it is only the 005010X217 version. It also doesn't look like [WPC has a schema](http://store.x12.org/store/healthcare-5010-tr3-schemas) for 278 005010X216 either. The 005010X216 definition is different enough that using the 278 schema without modifications may not be possible.

Does anyone know if BizTalk 2010 even truly supports 005010X216 and, if so, is there a schema available for it?

If not, does anyone know if there is a 3rd party component that supports 005010X216? I did a search of the usual open source repositories, but came up with nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The link you mentioned for the BizTalk schemas was for some 5010 version changes with BizTalk 2010.

On this link someone from Microsoft responded in the comments that the X216 version was not mandatory and was not being included: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkb2b/archive/2010/01/29/hipaa-5010-support-now-available-for-bts-2009.aspx.

So I recommend customizing the X217 version because it should have all of the features of X216. You will need to just remove the additions of the X217 version over the X216 version.

Thanks,